# how to properly display right to left language (arabic) in conky?

Tags: conky, right-to-left

how to properly display right to left language (arabic) in conky ?

here is the content of a file:

[image]

and here is conky screenshot:

[image]

Comment: A couple of workarounds are discussed here... https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/75. There's also a patch that has yet to be incorporated into the released version, but you'd have to recompile conky to use it.